# What is compactness?

Tags: logic

The proof, formal definition and academic explanations are easy to find but hard to understand. Can you please explain it in ordinary language with clear examples?

See the following references:

- https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/#3
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem

Comment: What definition are you looking at?  The topological definition would seem inappropriate for language.

Comment: This SEP entry says infinitary languages do not possess compactness:   https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/  which led me to imagine that a linguist might have something to say on the subject.
Here's the wp page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem

Comment: I added the references from your comment. You may want to edit it further.

Comment: @rgfuller can you explain what you mean by "which led me to imagine that a linguist might have something to say on the subject"? Do you mean to say that you think a linguist, whose field's theoretical base is the exact same as formal logic, would disagree with the proof that infinitary languages don't have compactness? They absolutely would not disagree, and I think that if this is what you meant, you are confused about what formal languages are.

Comment: No, I don't think a linguist would disagree.  I was only responding to the previous comment, and explaining my rationale for including the philosophy of language tag (which someone has edited out)

Answer (score 5):

*A simplified presentation*.

Compactness for First-order logic is related to the [Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Strong_completeness) of the *calculus* (i.e. [*proof system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Deductive_systems)) : in fact, the two mathematical results are equivalent (i.e. we can prove one of them from the other).

Both theorems link together the two views of a logical system : the so-called *syntactical* one (term, formula, derivation, consistency) and the *semantical* one (interpretation, model, satisfiability).

Completeness means that every [*logical consequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of a set of sentences is [*derivable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof) (i.e. *provable*), with the logical rules of the calculus, from the axioms.

The theorem is an *iff*.

The easy part is trivial : if a collection of first-order sentences has a model then every finite subset of it has a model.

Obviously, if the set **A** of sentences has a model that *satisfies* (i.e. makes them TRUE) all the sentences in it, then this model with also satisfies every subset of **A**.

The other part is less trivial : if every finite subset of a collection of first-order sentences has a model then the entire collection has one.

Sketch of the proof : assume not. If the collection **A** has no model, it is inconsistent. By Completeness, we can derive the contradiction using the rules of the calculus.

But a derivation in the calculus is a finite sequence of formulas (by definition of derivation) : thus, it can use only a *finite* subset of **A**.

Thus, this finite subset of **A** is itself contradictory, i.e. it has no model, contradicting the fact that every *finite* subset of **A** has one.

---

*Some more terminology*.

We say that a collection of sentences is *inconsistent* when we can derive (using the rules of the calculus) a contradiciton from it.

We say that a formula (a set of formulas) is *satisfied* by an interpretation when the said formula is TRUE in that interpretation.

We say that a formula (a set of formulas) is *satisfiable* when there is an interpretation that satisfies it.

Another link between the syntactical and the semantical views is that an inconsistent collection of sentences is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. it is impossible to find an interpretation that makes sumultaneously TRUE all the sentences in the collection, and vice versa.

Comment: I understand to "have a model" means to "have an interpretation."  If this is correct, then please explain why we cannot assign some arbitrary interpretation to any collection. In other words, what is the basis for saying that a collection has no model? How are collections with models distinguished from those without?

Comment: @rgfuller it's not "have an interpretation" as in any old interpretation. It's "have an interpretation with no contradictions", or have a *valid* interpretation. You can't just assign any interpretation to sentences and say "there, it has a model", because there is a huge chance you are not presenting a valid model. You probably are confused because people say it while leaving the word "valid" implicit, but validity is required.

Comment: @rgfuller Or maybe you know this and your question is different. It's like this, a model of a theory is an interpretation where each sentence is given a value of true or false. A valid interpretation is an interpretation where all of the axioms are true, and all of the theorems that are provable from the axioms are also true. Soundness and completeness assures us that this is doable if and only if all of the axioms are satisfied by the interpretation. Compactness means that infinite theories have a valid interpretation, or a model, if and only if every finite subset has a model.

Comment: My understanding of satisfaction comes from computer science. I do not get why interpretation has anything to do with satisfaction.  To me satisfaction seems purely mechanical, with no concern for the value of object constants.  A simple example would really help.

Comment: @rgfuller Computer science uses the same exact logic that mathematical logic uses and satisfaction means the exact same thing. A boolean sentence is satisfiable if and only if there is some interpretation that equates the entire sentence to true. That is exactly the same definition as with talking about models of formal theories. An interpretation *is* an assignment of values to variables. A boolean expression is satisfiable if and only if there is an interpretation, an assignment of True or False to it's atomic sentences, which equates it to True.

Comment: @rgfuller If you dont have an interpretation then you literally cannot talk about whether or not a boolean expression is satisfied. You have no way to know whether or not it's true unless you give it an interpretation. Is A^B true? Doesn't that depend on the interpretation, true or false, we give to A and B? Satisfaction is mechanical in the sense that *once you give an interpretation* it's mechanical to check whether or not it evaluates to true, but you obviously need an interpretation first. Again referring back to my first comments, we care about *valid* interpretations, not arbitrary ones.

Comment: "to have a model" is "to have an interpretation that makes sumultaneously TRUE all the sentences in the collection". The collection **{ A, ¬A }** is inconsistent and thus *unsatisfiable* : no interpretation can makes TRUE both formulas at the same time.

Comment: Please see the Herbrand Manifesto: intrologic.stanford.edu/extras/manifesto.html Michael Genesereth, the director of the Stanford Logic Group, introduces a new notion of semantics for FOL where a model is simply the subset of ground atoms of the language with a truth value of True. However, he states that with this approach FOL looses the property of compactness. With your explanation in mind, why would FOL loose the property of compactness with Herbrand semantics? Genesereth explains that there is no external universe.. but I don't understand how that matters.

Comment: @rgfuller - [Herbrand interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_interpretation) is not so a new concept; see [Herbrand's theorem (1930)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand%27s_theorem).

Comment: See the post : [Herbrand theorem works only with clauses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674679/herbrand-theorem-works-only-with-clauses) : H's Th is important because reduces the problem of satisfiability of FOL to the simpler case of prop logic. But the limitation is that it applies to *clauses* only. In that post you can see a simple example of a set of formulas that has a model but no Herbrand model.

Comment: Thank you, Could you offer a natural language paraphrasing of that example, to help clarify the distinction between a clause and an arbitrary closed formula?

Comment: @rgfuller - the interpretation is straightforward: we have a theory with two sentences : 1) "**a** is positive" and 2) "there is an obeject that is not positive". The model of this pseudo-theory is trivial in the domain of e.g. natural numbers. **But** if we restrict ourselves to Herbrand interpretations, where the only stuff is the syntactical one, due to the lack of function symbols, we have to restrict ourselves to interpretations with domain made of **only one** element : **a**. And the pseudo-theory has models that must have domains with at least **two** elements.

Comment: @rgfuller - a more "natural" example for **S={ p(a), ∃x¬p(x) }** can be : 1) "**a** is a *philosopher*" and 2) "there is someone that is not a *philosopher*".

Comment: @Not_Here My understanding of validity is that it is not concerned with interpretation. Modus ponens is valid regardless of any assignment of values to the object constants. If one or both of the premises are not semantically true, then the conclusion is is not guaranteed. The argument pattern is valid, but the argument itself is not sound. Did you mean to say 'sound' instead of 'valid' in your explanation of models, or is my understanding of 'valid' mistaken?

Comment: @rgfuller Your understanding of 'valid' is mistaken. "My understanding of validity is that it is not concerned with interpretation. Modus ponens is valid regardless of any assignment of values to the object constants" these two sentences contradict each other. Assigning values to variables is the literal definition of giving an interpretation.

Comment: @rgfuller I think it's sort of ironic that your blog has many posts about how important logic is and even trying to go into details about mathematical logic but you seem to be demonstrating here that you don't have even the fundamental concepts down. If our explanations haven't helped you, I'd recommend you picking up a textbook. I can try to explain further or I can recommend textbooks, but this has already gone on too long in the comments and the space constraints/inevitable deletion by mods saps my impetus to continue here. Let me know if you want me to email you or comment on your blog.

Comment: @NotHere Thank you. I do not see the contradiction. You seem to be saying that MP cannot be deemed to be valid until after the variables are given interperetations. Many people like I with backgrounds in CS have difficulty with the language and concepts of standard model theory. Michael Genesereth specifically sites that as the reason they teach Herbrand semantics at Stanford -- at least in the CS department, I'm not sure about philosophy. I would appreciate further discussion, by email if you'd like. If I have made a mistake on my blog then please leave a comment there.

Comment: @NotHere By "regardless of any assignment of values" I meant both "even if no assignment is made"  and "regardless of what the assignments may be"

Comment: @rgfuller Your blog doesn't have any contact information. Look, you can say "it doesn't matter what interpretation we give because it's true in every interpretation" but you can't say "we don't give it an interpretation" that makes literally no sense. You cannot make no assignments. But even still, this has nothing to do with models, you're talking about the validity of rules of deduction, not how valid is used in respect to models. [Read this and the link it gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Satisfiability).

Comment: @Not_Here Uninterpreted structures make perfect sense in EE and CS because circuits and programs should be correct (i.e. valid) regardless of the inputs and even when inputs are absent. The term I am accustomed to with respect to the truthfulness of interpretations is 'soundness', not 'validity'.  But I accept that usage and I thank you for the clarification, and for the link. My email is my username here (at) my blog URL.

Comment: @rgfuller You're still making a conflation between syntax and semantics when you talk about your CS example, my background was CS before I entered this field and I can assure you that you are under false impressions about many things.

Comment: @Not_Here Then I would appreciate further explanation, if *not_here*, then by email.

Comment: @Not_Here I appreciate the email. My responses have all bounced. please send one that works.

Comment: @rgfuller Sent.

Comment: @Not_Here still bouncing